# Postgresql Query performance optimization

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I have a query which runs fast during off period but when there is load it runs very slow.
In the New Relic it sometimes shows to run 5-8mins.
The query looks simple but the View definition may be not that simple.
So wanted to know if there is any scope of optimization
Database version - `"PostgreSQL 10.14 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 4.9.4, 64-bit"`
The query which comes up in any monitoring tool is:

```
SELECT
    esnpartvie0_.esn_id AS col_0_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.esn AS col_1_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.quarter_point AS col_2_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.work_order_number AS col_3_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.site AS col_4_0_,
    sum(esnpartvie0_.critical) AS col_5_0_,
    sum(esnpartvie0_.numshort) AS col_6_0_,
    sum(esnpartvie0_.wa) AS col_7_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.customer AS col_8_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.adj_accum_date AS col_9_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.g2_otr AS col_10_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.induct_date AS col_11_0_,
    min(esnpartvie0_.delta) AS col_12_0_,
    esnpartvie0_.fiscal_week_bucket_date AS col_13_0_
FROM
    moa.esn_part_view esnpartvie0_
WHERE
    esnpartvie0_.esn_id = 140339
GROUP BY
    esnpartvie0_.esn_id,
    esnpartvie0_.esn,
    esnpartvie0_.quarter_point,
    esnpartvie0_.work_order_number,
    esnpartvie0_.site,
    esnpartvie0_.customer,
    esnpartvie0_.adj_accum_date,
    esnpartvie0_.g2_otr,
    esnpartvie0_.induct_date,
    esnpartvie0_.fiscal_week_bucket_date
```

---

The Explain Analyze, buffer plan for the same is and the link (https://explain.depesz.com/s/mr76#html)

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=69684.12..69684.17 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=976.163..976.228 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: esnpartvie0_.esn_id, esnpartvie0_.esn, esnpartvie0_.quarter_point, esnpartvie0_.work_order_number, esnpartvie0_.site, esnpartvie0_.customer, esnpartvie0_.adj_accum_date, esnpartvie0_.g2_otr, esnpartvie0_.induct_date, esnpartvie0_.fiscal_week_bucket_date"
"  Buffers: shared hit=20301, temp read=48936 written=6835"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=69684.12..69684.13 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=976.153..976.219 rows=14 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: esnpartvie0_.esn, esnpartvie0_.quarter_point, esnpartvie0_.work_order_number, esnpartvie0_.site, esnpartvie0_.customer, esnpartvie0_.adj_accum_date, esnpartvie0_.g2_otr, esnpartvie0_.induct_date, esnpartvie0_.fiscal_week_bucket_date"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=20301, temp read=48936 written=6835"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on esnpartvie0_  (cost=69684.02..69684.11 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=976.078..976.158 rows=14 loops=1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=20290, temp read=48936 written=6835"
"              ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=69684.02..69684.10 rows=1 width=2016) (actual time=976.077..976.155 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                    Group Key: e.esn_id, w.number, ed.adj_accum_date, (COALESCE(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start, ed.gate_1_stop, p.part_id, st.name, mat.name, so.name, dr.name, hpc.hpc_status_name, module.module_name, c.customer_id, m.model_id, ef.engine_family_id, s.site_id, ws.name, ic.comment"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=20290, temp read=48936 written=6835"
"                    CTE indexed_comments"
"                      ->  WindowAgg  (cost=40573.82..45076.80 rows=225149 width=118) (actual time=182.537..291.895 rows=216974 loops=1)"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=5226, temp read=3319 written=3327"
"                            ->  Sort  (cost=40573.82..41136.69 rows=225149 width=110) (actual time=182.528..215.549 rows=216974 loops=1)"
"                                  Sort Key: part_comment.part_id, part_comment.created_at DESC"
"                                  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 26552kB"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=5226, temp read=3319 written=3327"
"                                  ->  Seq Scan on part_comment  (cost=0.00..7474.49 rows=225149 width=110) (actual time=0.014..38.209 rows=216974 loops=1)"
"                                        Buffers: shared hit=5223"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=24607.21..24607.22 rows=1 width=717) (actual time=976.069..976.133 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                          Sort Key: w.number, ed.adj_accum_date, (COALESCE(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start, ed.gate_1_stop, p.part_id, st.name, mat.name, so.name, dr.name, hpc.hpc_status_name, module.module_name, c.customer_id, m.model_id, ef.engine_family_id, s.site_id, ws.name, ic.comment"
"                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=20290, temp read=48936 written=6835"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1010.23..24607.20 rows=1 width=717) (actual time=442.381..976.017 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=20287, temp read=48936 written=6835"
"                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.94..24598.88 rows=1 width=697) (actual time=442.337..975.670 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                      Join Filter: (ic.part_id = p.part_id)"
"                                      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 824838"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=20245, temp read=48936 written=6835"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.94..19518.95 rows=1 width=181) (actual time=56.148..57.676 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=15019"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.81..19518.35 rows=1 width=183) (actual time=56.139..57.635 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=15019"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.67..19517.67 rows=1 width=181) (actual time=56.133..57.598 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=15019"
"                                                        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.55..19516.82 rows=1 width=179) (actual time=56.124..57.544 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=15019"
"                                                              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.42..19516.04 rows=1 width=178) (actual time=56.105..57.439 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=14991"
"                                                                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.28..19515.37 rows=1 width=175) (actual time=56.089..57.335 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=14963"
"                                                                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.14..19514.77 rows=1 width=170) (actual time=56.068..57.206 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                                                                Join Filter: (e.work_scope_id = ws.work_scope_id)"
"                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=14935"
"                                                                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1009.14..19513.55 rows=1 width=166) (actual time=56.043..57.102 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                                                                      Join Filter: (e.esn_id = p.esn_id)"
"                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=14921"
"                                                                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9.14..31.40 rows=1 width=125) (actual time=0.081..0.130 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=15"
"                                                                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.87..23.08 rows=1 width=118) (actual time=0.069..0.117 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=12"
"                                                                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.73..21.86 rows=1 width=108) (actual time=0.055..0.102 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=10"
"                                                                                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.60..21.65 rows=1 width=46) (actual time=0.046..0.091 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=8"
"                                                                                                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.31..13.34 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.036..0.081 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                    Hash Cond: (m.model_id = e.model_id)"
"                                                                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=5"
"                                                                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on model m  (cost=0.00..4.39 rows=239 width=17) (actual time=0.010..0.038 rows=240 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=8.30..8.30 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                                                          ->  Index Scan using esn_pkey on esn e  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                                Index Cond: (esn_id = 140339)"
"                                                                                                                                Filter: active"
"                                                                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                                              ->  Index Scan using work_order_pkey on work_order w  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                                    Index Cond: (work_order_id = e.work_order_id)"
"                                                                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                                        ->  Index Scan using engine_family_pkey on engine_family ef  (cost=0.14..0.20 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                              Index Cond: (engine_family_id = m.engine_family_id)"
"                                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                                  ->  Index Scan using site_pkey on site s  (cost=0.14..1.15 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                        Index Cond: (site_id = ef.site_id)"
"                                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                                                            ->  Index Scan using customer_pkey on customer c  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                                                  Index Cond: (customer_id = e.customer_id)"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=3"
"                                                                                      ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..19481.78 rows=29 width=41) (actual time=55.958..56.949 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                                                                                            Workers Planned: 2"
"                                                                                            Workers Launched: 2"
"                                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=14906"
"                                                                                            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on part p  (cost=0.00..18478.88 rows=12 width=41) (actual time=51.855..52.544 rows=5 loops=3)"
"                                                                                                  Filter: (active AND (esn_id = 140339))"
"                                                                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 226662"
"                                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=14906"
"                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on work_scope ws  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=10 width=12) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=14)"
"                                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=14"
"                                                                          ->  Index Scan using source_pkey on source so  (cost=0.14..0.57 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=14)"
"                                                                                Index Cond: (p.source_id = source_id)"
"                                                                                Buffers: shared hit=28"
"                                                                    ->  Index Scan using status_pkey on status st  (cost=0.13..0.56 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=14)"
"                                                                          Index Cond: (p.status_id = status_id)"
"                                                                          Buffers: shared hit=28"
"                                                              ->  Index Scan using material_stream_pkey on material_stream mat  (cost=0.13..0.56 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=14)"
"                                                                    Index Cond: (p.material_stream_id = material_stream_id)"
"                                                                    Buffers: shared hit=28"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using dr_status_pkey on dr_status dr  (cost=0.13..0.56 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=14)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (p.dr_status_id = dr_status_id)"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using hpc_status_pkey on hpc_status hpc  (cost=0.13..0.56 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=14)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (p.hpc_status_id = hpc_status_id)"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using module_pkey on module  (cost=0.14..0.57 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=14)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (p.module_id = module_id)"
"                                      ->  CTE Scan on indexed_comments ic  (cost=0.00..5065.85 rows=1126 width=520) (actual time=13.043..61.251 rows=58917 loops=14)"
"                                            Filter: (comment_index = 1)"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 158057"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=5226, temp read=48936 written=6835"
"                                ->  Index Scan using esn_dates_esn_id_key on esn_dates ed  (cost=0.29..8.32 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=14)"
"                                      Index Cond: (esn_id = 140339)"
"                                      Filter: ((gate_3_stop_actual AND (gate_3_stop >= now())) OR (gate_3_stop IS NULL) OR ((NOT gate_3_stop_actual) AND (gate_3_stop IS NOT NULL) AND (gate_3_stop >= (now() - '730 days'::interval))))"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=42"
"Planning time: 6.564 ms"
"Execution time: 988.335 ms"
```

---

The actual View definition on which the above select is running

```
with indexed_comments as (
select
    part_comment.part_id,
    part_comment.comment,
    row_number() over (partition by part_comment.part_id
order by
    part_comment.created_at desc) as comment_index
from
    moa.part_comment
        )
 select
    e.esn_id,
    e.name as esn,
    e.is_qp_engine as quarter_point,
    w.number as work_order_number,
    case
        when (p.part_id is null) then 0
        else p.part_id
    end as part_id,
    p.part_number,
    p.part_description,
    p.quantity,
    st.name as status,
    p.status_id,
    mat.name as material_stream,
    p.material_stream_id,
    so.name as source,
    p.source_id,
    p.oem,
    p.po_number,
    p.manual_cso_commit,
    p.auto_cso_commit,
    coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit) as calculated_cso_commit,
    (coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start) + p.accum_offset) as adjusted_accum,
    dr.name as dr_status,
    p.dr_status_id,
    p.airway_bill,
    p.core_material,
    hpc.hpc_status_name as hpc_status,
    p.hpc_status_id,
    module.module_name,
    p.module_id,
    c.name as customer,
    c.customer_id,
    m.name as model,
    m.model_id,
    ef.name as engine_family,
    ef.engine_family_id,
    s.label as site,
    s.site_id,
    case
        when (coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit) > coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start)) then 1
        else 0
    end as critical,
    case
        when (coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit) <= coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start)) then 1
        else 0
    end as numshort,
    case
        when ((p.esn_id is not null)
        and (coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit) is null)) then 1
        else 0
    end as wa,
    ed.adj_accum_date,
    (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)) as g2_otr,
    ed.gate_0_start as induct_date,
    coalesce((coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0))) - max(coalesce(p.manual_cso_commit, p.auto_cso_commit))), 0) as delta,
    coalesce(ed.adj_accum_date, (ed.gate_1_stop + coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0)), ed.gate_0_start) as fiscal_week_bucket_date,
    p.po_line_num,
    p.ship_out,
    p.receipt,
    p.crit_ship,
    e.work_scope_id,
    ws.name as work_scope,
    p.late_call,
    p.ex_esn,
    p.accum_offset,
    ic.comment as latest_comment
from
    (((((((((((((((moa.esn e
join moa.work_order w
        using (work_order_id))
join moa.model m
        using (model_id))
join moa.engine_family ef on
    ((m.engine_family_id = ef.engine_family_id)))
join moa.site s on
    ((ef.site_id = s.site_id)))
join moa.customer c
        using (customer_id))
left join moa.part p on
    (((e.esn_id = p.esn_id)
        and (p.active <> false))))
left join moa.work_scope ws on
    ((e.work_scope_id = ws.work_scope_id)))
left join moa.source so on
    ((p.source_id = so.source_id)))
left join moa.status st on
    ((p.status_id = st.status_id)))
left join moa.material_stream mat
        using (material_stream_id))
left join moa.dr_status dr
        using (dr_status_id))
left join moa.hpc_status hpc
        using (hpc_status_id))
left join moa.module module
        using (module_id))
left join indexed_comments ic on
    (((ic.part_id = p.part_id)
        and (ic.comment_index = 1))))
join moa.esn_dates ed on
    ((e.esn_id = ed.esn_id)))
where
    ((e.active = true)
        and (((ed.gate_3_stop_actual = true)
            and (ed.gate_3_stop >= now()))
            or (ed.gate_3_stop is null)
                or ((ed.gate_3_stop_actual = false)
                    and (ed.gate_3_stop is not null)
                        and (ed.gate_3_stop >= (now() - '730 days'::interval)))))
group by
    e.esn_id,
    w.number,
    s.label,
    c.name,
    p.active,
    ed.adj_accum_date,
    coalesce(ed.gate_2_otr, 0),
    ed.gate_0_start,
    ed.gate_1_stop,
    p.part_id,
    st.name,
    mat.name,
    so.name,
    dr.name,
    hpc.hpc_status_name,
    module.module_name,
    c.customer_id,
    m.name,
    m.model_id,
    ef.name,
    ef.engine_family_id,
    s.site_id,
    ws.name,
    ic.comment;
```

Comment: Can you capture the plan when it is being slow?  auto_explain is good for this.

Comment: the EXPLAIN plan is taken during the peak time

Comment: Write less complicated views  Also, don't use `ORDER BY` in view definitions

Comment: But it took less than a second.  Maybe the problem is the network is saturated?  But for only one row that is not plausible.  Maybe 'peak time' and 'slow time' are not the same?  Maybe it is the app server not the database that is slow?

Comment: during peak time, the DB CPU is hitting 100% quite often , is it because of the query or the load at peak time? In off peak hours the app is quite fast

Comment: I don't know how New Relic decides on how long you have been waiting on something.  If you try to run this 500 times in quick succession, then sure you will be waiting 8 minutes for the last one of those to finish, if they have to run sequentially.

Answer (score 4):

What a horrific query.

Most of the time is going to this:

> ```
> ->  CTE Scan on indexed_comments ic  (cost=0.00..5065.85 rows=1126 width=520) (actual time=13.043..61.251 rows=58917 loops=14)"
> ```

And the main culprit there is a misestimation of upper sibling node.  It thinks it will need to do the CTE Scan one time, but it actually needs to do it 14 times (although apparently returning the same answer each time).  If it knew it would do it repeatedly, it would set up a hash table rather than just iterate through it each time.  But since setting up the hash requires one iteration through it, it doesn't seem to save anything if it thinks it only needs one iteration in the first place.

I don't know how to fix the estimation problem.  But you could compute the ranks on the fly, rather than computing all up front then needing to search through them.  You would do that with a LATERAL join.

Change

```
left join indexed_comments ic on
    (((ic.part_id = p.part_id)
        and (ic.comment_index = 1))))
```

to

```
left join lateral (select comment from part_comment pc where p.part_id=pc.part_id order by created_at desc limit 1) ic on true
```

and get rid of the `with indexed_comments as...`

For this to be fast you would need an index `ON part_comment (part_id, created_at)`

Comment: Hi jjanes...indeed its a horrific query :) though not written by me..I will try to implement your suggestion and will let you know how it performs in production. should I remove the whole section of with indexed_comments as... till before select

Comment: Yes, all of the WITH down to closing `)` just before the SELECT.  If you know why the estimation is off, you could alternatively try to address that.

Comment: what estimation ..I didnt get it

Comment: oh ok..never mind...I got it...the difference between cost numbers and actual time numbers